# how to sort money into its separate notes?

Tags: c#, loops

I'm busy making a "cash-up" program and trying to figure out how to sort a sum of money from a cash register into its separate values (notes and coins) from highest to lowest. I'm really struggling to think of how i would do this in a valid way.
what i thought of was something like this:

```
while (sum>=0){
   if(sum <0 R200&& sum % 200 !>0){   //R200 is the amount of 200 rand notes in the register
   sum = sum - 200.00;
   }//endif
}//endwhile
```

but when i try this i end up wither with an infinite loop or it doesn't actually minus the amount

Comment: Are you sure this is [tag:c#]? `<0` and `!>` don't look like code I recognize.

Comment: I think you have to provide minimum example of input and expected output. It's not clear, as is now, what program has to do.

Comment: the second answer sums up basically what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a loop, you can simply divide the money and then use the remainder operator to subtract it from the total money.

Compilable example:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal money = 255.50M;

        int hundredDollarBills = subtract(ref money, 100);
        int fiftyDollarBills = subtract(ref money, 50);
        int twentyDollarBills = subtract(ref money, 20);
        int tenDollarBills = subtract(ref money, 10);
        int singleDillarBills = subtract(ref money, 1);
        int fiftyCentCoins = subtract(ref money, 0.50M);
        int twentyCentCoins = subtract(ref money, 0.20M);
        int tenCentCoins = subtract(ref money, 0.10M);
        int fiveCentCoins = subtract(ref money, 0.05M);
        int twoCentCoins = subtract(ref money, 0.02M);
        int oneCentCoins = subtract(ref money, 0.01M);
        Console.WriteLine("Total amount of change: " + hundredDollarBills + " $100,\n" + fiftyDollarBills + " $50,\n" + twentyDollarBills + " $20,\n" + tenDollarBills + " $10,\n" + singleDillarBills + " $1,\n" + fiftyCentCoins + " $0.50,\n" + twentyCentCoins + " $0.20,\n" + tenCentCoins + " $0.10,\n" + fiveCentCoins + " $0.05,\n" + twoCentCoins + " $0.02,\n" + oneCentCoins + " $0.01");
        Console.WriteLine("Total money left over: " + money);
    }

    private static int subtract(ref decimal money, decimal amount)
    {
        int amtOfChange = (int) Math.Floor(money / amount);
        money %= amount;
        return amtOfChange;
    }
}
```

For an input of $255.50, this code prints this result:

Total amount of change: 2 $100,

1 $50,

0 $20,

0 $10,

5 $1,

1 $0.50,

0 $0.20,

0 $0.10,

0 $0.05,

0 $0.02,

0 $0.01

Edit: obviously this code can be improved a lot, it serves as an example of how to do the calculations!

Comment: You need to learn about `DRY`.  Don't repeat yourself.  Put the common steps into a separate method that does this `(int) Math.Floor(money / xxxx);` and takes `xxxx` as an arg.

Comment: I know about `DRY`, I just didn't have enough time to apply it here. As I said in the edit this merely serves as an example of how to do the calculations OP wants. I'll edit my post in a bit.

Comment: Updated my post with a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have an enum like this:

```
enum CashType { c1, c5, c10, c25, c50, d1, d2, d5, d10, d20, d50, d100 }
```

You can do something like this:

```
var denominationsToCentValue = new Dictionary<CashType, int>()
{
    { CashType.d100, 10000 },
    { CashType.d50, 5000 },
    { CashType.d20, 2000 },
    { CashType.d10, 1000 },
    { CashType.d5, 500 },
    { CashType.d2, 200 },
    { CashType.d1, 100 },
    { CashType.c50, 50 },
    { CashType.c25, 25 },
    { CashType.c10, 10 },
    { CashType.c5, 5 },
    { CashType.c1, 1 }
};


var sortedCash = new Dictionary<CashType, int>();
var cashInRegister = 342.11M;
int cashInRegisterInCents = (int)(100 * cashInRegister);

foreach (var denom in denominationsToCentValue)
{
    int count = cashInRegisterInCents / denom.Value;
    cashInRegisterInCents -= count * denom.Value;

    sortedCash.Add(denom.Key, count);
}
```